# Call Swift classes from Obj-C class that was bridged header to Swift Project

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, swift

I have a Swift Project, and I'm using bridging-header to call some Obj-c Classes and it works great. and I can easily use Obj-C classes alongside Swift.

But now, I have problem calling one of my Swift classes from Obj-C.

I mean I want to  call fun `x` from `y` class, which is a swift class, from another obj-c class in my project.

I've used 'y-Swift.h'  and some other methods, but non of them worked. :(

Comment: Did you have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002369/how-to-call-objective-c-code-from-swift (which explains calling from Swift to ObjC *and* vice-versa)?

Comment: @MartinR of course. that's how I used Obj-C Classes in Swift Project, but in this situation it does not help.

Comment: Its not really clear what you are asking, can you please add code examples and explain in which way it's failing for you.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation, you have to use something like this `ProductName/ProductModuleName-Swift.h`. You can get your product name from the project settings in **XCode**.

Another way to import is as followed:

```
#import "ProductModuleName-Swift.h"
```

Comment: Still says : 'ProductName/ProductModuleName-Swift.h' file not found. :(

Comment: Use `#import "ProductModuleName-Swift.h"` instead. Find your product name in your project settings. Avoid typo. Cheers.